# Semver policy with Node.js engine enforcing

Tags: node.js, semantic-versioning

What is the policy when one enforces a newer (Node.js) engine version?
Is it semver **MAJOR** or semver **MINOR**?

**Context:** I'm the author of a [package with 2k stars on github](https://github.com/cronvel/terminal-kit) (30k downloads per week) and I recently enforced Node.js v14 (because I'm starting to use *optional chaining* and *null coalescing* everywhere), and made it a new MINOR version.

But some of my users are complaining and asking me to make that change a new **MAJOR** version.
Also previously, nobody complained when I enforced Node.js v10 on a **MINOR** version.

I can't find any resource about that matter, even the [semver spec](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html) does not specify this (not even in the FAQ section). The spec only talks about the API.

I want to keep my project in line with the correct policy.

Comment: I realize it's a matter of opinion, but nearly every module I've used that bumps node.js requirements makes that a major version bump.

Comment: One thing bumping a major version does is that an `npm update` command will not auto-update major version bumps; I've more or less come to expect that if `npm update` can update things, it won't (likely) introduce major breaking changes like minimum node versions.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting Isaacs from Twitter (@izs), author of the *semver* npm package (and by the way founder of *npm*):

> I've always considered SemVer Major to mean "you will have to change something on your end to start using this update".
>
> If the previous version worked on platform version X, and the new version requires platform version X+n, then that qualifies, yes.

Comment: A slight clarification to my tweet is: major means "I _expect_ that you will have to change on your end to use this update". Difference is subtle, but important. 

Frequently users will come to depend on an underspecified, "working, but not as intended", internal, or just plain broken aspect of a program. (Every program worth considering has these.) When a bug is fixed, these might change, requiring changes by users. But those are not expected or intended; the user may have been Doing It Wrong, or it may be a bug, or it may be a bug that the developer is within reason to decide is WONTFIX.

Answer (score 3):

This has been [discussed here in many threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsemver%5Dtransitive+dependency) as well [SemVer discusions](https://github.com/semver/semver/issues?q=is%3Aissue+transitive). Some claim it is subjective, but I think if you were to replace the opinionated terms (API, Package, Product) with something like OBV (Object Being Versioned), you will see that spec and most of the knowledgeable participants agree with each other.

**If your customer's build environment is broken because you issued a minor or patch release, they have every right to complain**. The [SemVer spec](https://semver.org/) really focuses more on API versioning, than packages, though it does mention the later in a few places. So the key here is, most of us never actually version just an API, we version packages and the manifests within them, which also implicitly/explicitly include transitive dependencies.

The whole point of SemVer is to communicate risks to consumers of those OBV's. As a publisher, you are responsible for the entire dependency tree that you include in your OBV's. You can chose whether to implicitly or explicitly introduce a breaking transitive dependency into your OBV, therefore **it is your responsibility to inform your customers of the risk by bumping the major version**.